# Change href using textbox with Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, button, click

I have a textbox and an Asp.Net button.

I am trying to open a weblink using this [prettybox](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) Iframe

Now I am able to open If I give the link as shown below which is mentioned in the link provided:

```
<a href="http://www.apple.com?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]">Apple.com</a>
```

But instead of doing that way I need to provide the web address in the textbox and If I click the button I need to open the website using Iframe.

I am able to open with a button click as shown below.

```
 <a id="various3" href="" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"><asp:Button ID="btnShowThumbnailImage" 
    runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnShowThumbnailImage_Click" /></a>
```

And I am unable to get working If I do not provide the href in the href tag and providing it in the textbox.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=btnShowThumbnailImage.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").trigger('click');
        });

        $('#<%=txtWebsiteAddress.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val());
        });


        $("#<%=btnShowThumbnailImage.ClientID %>").click(function () {

            $("#various3").trigger('click');

        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            width: '75%',
            height: '75%',
            animationSpeed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
            opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
            showTitle: true /* true/false */
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my button:

```
 <a id="various3" href="" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"><asp:Button ID="btnShowThumbnailImage" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnShowThumbnailImage_Click" /></a>
```

So when I click the button its just showing me the spinner and not opening anything as shown in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the plugin by explicity calling `prettyPhoto` on the anchor element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[iframes]']").prettyPhoto();
}
```

By the way if you dont have to specify the href in the anchor you should alteast specify `javascript:void(0);` to make it look like a link in all the browsers because browsers like Firefox do not display them as a link if no `href` is specified unless there is any `css` applied on the element to show it as a link.

Comment: Sorry I did not mentioned here and I have done that too and updated my code with that and after doing that It is showing me the same.